# Select one parent property and all children using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of sections and each section has a collection of questions. If I want to select all the questions under all the sections, this works

```
Sections.SelectMany(s=>s.Questions)
```

But now I also want the section number. So if I try something like this

```
 Sections.SelectMany(s=>s.Questions,s.SectionNumber)
```

it throws compilation error.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use anonymous type here:

```
Sections.SelectMany(s => s.Questions, (s, q) => new { Question = q, s.SectionNumber })
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's anonymous, or a named type, or what.  Any method of encapsulating both objects into a single object is fine.